# Is there any way to insert data at the bottom of the table?

Tags: python, sql-server

I created a table importing data from a csv file into a SQL Server table. The table contains about 6000 rows that are all float. I am trying to insert a new row using `INSERT` (I am using Python/Spyder and SQL Server Management Studio) and it does insert the row but not at the bottom of the table but towards the middle. I have no idea why it does that. This is the code that I am using:

```
def create (conn):
    print ("Create")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute ("insert into PricesTest 

(Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4,Price5,Price6,Price7,Price8,Price9,Price10,Price
 11,Price12) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
 (46,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44))

    conn.commit()
    read (conn)
```

Any idea why this is happening? What I should add to my code to "force" that row to be added at the bottom of the table? Many thanks.

Comment: 1) Tables are unordered sets by design 2) Why so many Price columns?

Comment: Tables don't have a "bottom" (or top). They are stored as unordered heaps, with the absence of a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, or otherwise the **pages** will be sorted in the order of said index.

Comment: to add to @ThierryLathuille 's comment ... also keep in mind that simply using a `ORDER BY` can still result into getting a non deterministic ("random") sort where the values are equal, you need to handle possible ties in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Lukasz: Because each price corresponds to a different contract of the same asset, e.g. Oil has many prices, one for each delivery contract. Is there any way to "order" the table, i.e. that the first row corresponds to today's prices and the last one to the oldest date of prices that I have available?

Comment: *"Because each price corresponds to a different contract of the same asset"* That isn't how you should be designing your data. You should be normalising your data; build tall not wide.

Comment: Ordering happens when you run a query. If each price relates to a contract you should probably have aContractPrice table with a row for each price, next to the ID of the contract. Then if you add or remove a contract it will be easier than making new columns

Answer (score 1):

I managed to sort it out following different suggestions posted here. Basically I was conceptually wrong to think that tables in MS SQL have an order. I am now working with the data in my table using the ORDER BY dates (I added dates as my first column) and works well. Many thanks all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the new rows are inserted without any order by default because the server has no rule to order the newly inserted rows (there is no primary key defined). You should have created an identity column before importing your data (even you can do it now):
`Id Int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key` 
This will ensure all rows will be added at the end of the table. 
More info on the data type you could use on w3school : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: `auto_increment` is a MySQL term.

Comment: An identity column does NOT do what the OP desires. It will make retrieving the rows in the order added possible but only when used properly in a query.